# Chutzpah tests discovered in wrong directory with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: chutzpah

I have recently added a new user onto my domain and swapped over to use that continue developing a project using git.

I've just re-run the unit tests and chutzpah is looking in the old source directory for js file:

"C:\Users\Liam-Laptop\Source\Repos\InvestorsEdgeWeb\AtlasWeb\Scripts\Atlas\Objects"

whereas it should be looking at:

C:\Users\Liam\Source\Repos\InvestorsEdgeWeb\AtlasWeb\Scripts\Atlas\Objects

I don't seem to have a chutzpah.json file so where is it getting it's settings from and how do I change it?

Comment: How are you running the tests? From command line or VS?

Comment: It was a real school boy error - I had some includes that pointed to my original source! Thanks for coming back to me.